# Ubuntu Server 18.10 - No video mode activated

Tags: boot, server, grub2, plymouth

When booting, Ubuntu Server 18.10 shows a "Error: no video mode activated" text message and then shows the animated Ubuntu logo.

[image: boot logo image]

¿How can i get rid of that error message?

My /etc/default/grub content is

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"
```

Comment: Might be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/699802

Comment: By the way Duplicate "quiet splash" is not needed.`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`   See `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`

Comment: I tried nomodeset, copying the fonts, setting a resolution, setting a timeout > 0, etc.. :(

Comment: Without GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX with quiet splash boot logo doesn't show up :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running these commands fixed it for me:

```
sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. It will prevent running that script. Are you saying that not running the script will allow grub to show the grub console? Because I get the console only if I hit the Esc key right now.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/default/grub

```
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

and run 'update-grub'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the accepted answer, but you should activate the menu option in GRUB if you would like to get rid of the message:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then comment the part where it says hidden and add menu instead:

```
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Close the file, and update GRUB by the following command:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Source:
https://pov.es/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-fixing-the-error-no-video-mode-activated-message-on-boot/

Answer (score -1):

Well in my experience when i # Uncomment GRUB_TERMINAL=console in "Linux only" OS, this bug appeared and upon commenting it hides it smoothly but there is a strange wait-up in the absence of message**(what is it?)**.

If you are dual-booting OS, then you must # uncomment it to bring back the boot menu.

It appears that the dual boot menu generates this error, (somehow) in the absence of dual boot system **as if it was not designed for a single linux distro operating alone.**